# P-value Computation in Quantile Regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, p-value, statsmodels, quantile-regression

How can be the p-values be computed in quantile regression?
I can see pre-existing packages in R(quantreg) and Python(statsmodel) arriving at the p-values in Quantile Regression.
Kindly provide reference or steps of the computation.

Comment: See Chapter 3 of Koenker (2005) Quantile Regression.

Comment: @utobi are they using p-value?

Comment: AFAIR, inference in statsmodels is the same as in, or similar to, the Stata documentation. Main part is that computing standard errors (cov_params) requires a local kernel density estimate because of the kink in the objective function. p-values and confidence intervals are computed from cov_params in the usual way.

Comment: @Josef kindly provide the link of the documentation, if possible.